# How set a sub-report in a master report with multiple reports in the sub-report based on user click action?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence

I have a main report in SSRS 2012. In main report, I have a table with 4 rows. I have set each row an action attribute as 'Go To Report'. It runs proper. I have used parameters also. On clicking particular row, it go to particular report (other than main report, linking).

Now, what I want is, I have used sub-report in the main report. The sub-report is initially show in the main report with available parameters of the main report. But I want this sub-report to be dynamic, like in the same sub-report, I want to show multiple sub-reports based on the user click.

For example, If I click the first row of a table in the main report, it should show me 1 sub-report on the same main report. When I click second row of a table in main report, it should show me 2 sub-report on the same main report & so on.

Any ideas, suggestion are welcome. Other options rather than this idea are also welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged with Crystal Reports, you are asking about SSRS.

Comment: Ooop's. Thought Crystal reports as a part of reporting services by MS. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want report parts, which are what you describe; not whole reports but rather sections that take parameters that you would embed in your main report. You create a report part, publish it, then any report can use it by embedding it and passing parameters.  They're great for reusability. I'm not sure how to refresh them based on actions in the main report, but I bet you it's possible.

Report parts are here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee635721.aspx

Of course you can show/hide either a Row Group or Tablix. You can set the Row Group Properties Visibility to have an expression such as:
= IIF(Parameters!ViewOption.Value = "Expanded View: All Sections Expanded", False, True)
so user can click on it to expand.

Or you can show/hide the tablix with Tablix Properties Visibility.

Comment: Yes BClaydon. Thank you. I am confused with this Report Designer, is it a SSRS itself or any other tool. Because, it requires a Report Designer to publish report parts so that later you can embed those in your master report.

Comment: @Aditya, Report Designer and Report Builder are Microsoft tools for SSRS reports. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220460(v=sql.105).aspx I have no idea why we can do report parts in Report Builder and not in BIDS (the Visual Studio report builder), it drives me crazy. I hear it's changing in SQL Server 2012 though.

Comment: Nope. I am working with SQL Server 2012. Doesn't seems a big change. Same graphical look, little bit more functions that we usually do not use. One thing I would like to share, it seems me funny. There is no function for Distinct values in SSRS (for parameter values). We can count Distinct values but can not get Distinct values.